# Asignar Roles al Crear un Usuario en MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, seguridad, users-roles

Resulta que soy nuevo en MVC, estoy haciendo un proyecto de permisos y roles donde al crear un usuario se agregue este a la tablas de usuarios que genera entity framework:

Tengo una clase Utilities.cs donde creo los roles y los usuarios a tráves de métodos:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Permisos_Roles.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Permisos_Roles.Classes
{
    public class Utilities : IDisposable
   {
    private static ApplicationDbContext userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public static void CreateRoleASP(string roleName)
    {
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(userContext));//crear rol

        var roleASP = new IdentityRole
        {
            Name = roleName,
        };

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))//chequea si el rol existe
        {
            roleManager.Create(roleASP);
        }
    }

    public static void CreateUserASP(string email, string roleName)
    {
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext));//crear ususario

        var userASP = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Email = email,
            UserName = email,
        };

        userManager.Create(userASP, email);//crea usuario
        userManager.AddToRole(userASP.Id, roleName);//asigna rol, no me deja guardar role de otra tabla
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        userContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

El problema radica en el método CrearUserASP:

```
 public static void CreateUserASP(string email, string roleName)
    {
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext));//crear ususario

        var userASP = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Email = email,
            UserName = email,
        };

        userManager.Create(userASP, email);//crea usuario
        userManager.AddToRole(userASP.Id, roleName);//asigna rol, no me deja guardar role de otra tabla
    }
```

Ya que al momento de llamar el método en el Create de UsuariosController:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdUsuario,Nombres,Apellidos,NombreUsuario,Email,IdCargo,IdRol")] Usuario usuario)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Usuario.Add(usuario);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                Utilities.CreateUserASP(usuario.Email, "User");//solo con string funciona
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
                ViewBag.IdCargo = new SelectList(db.Cargo, "IdCargo", "Cargo1", usuario.IdCargo);
                ViewBag.IdRol = new SelectList(db.Rol, "IdRole", "Rol1", usuario.IdRol);
                return View(usuario);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.IdCargo = new SelectList(db.Cargo, "IdCargo", "Cargo1", usuario.IdCargo);
        ViewBag.IdRol = new SelectList(db.Rol, "IdRole", "Rol1", usuario.IdRol);
        return View(usuario);
    }
```

Solo me deja agregarlo de forma manual, y lo que deseo es que este rol sea asignado desde una tabla foranea llamada Roles, puesto que tengo IdRole y Rol1 que son el Id y el nombre del rol respectivamente del controlador de mi tabla Roles.

Controlador Roles:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Permisos_Roles.Classes;
using Permisos_Roles.Models;

namespace Permisos_Roles.Controllers
{
 public class RolesController : Controller
 {
    private Permisos_RolesEntities db = new Permisos_RolesEntities();

    // GET: Roles
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Rol.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Roles/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Rol rol = db.Rol.Find(id);
        if (rol == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(rol);
    }

    // GET: Roles/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Roles/Create
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdRole,Rol1")] Rol rol)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Rol.Add(rol);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                Utilities.CreateRoleASP(rol.Rol1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
                return View(rol);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(rol);
    }

    // GET: Roles/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Rol rol = db.Rol.Find(id);
        if (rol == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(rol);
    }

    // POST: Roles/Edit/5
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "IdRole,Rol1")] Rol rol)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(rol).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(rol);
    }

    // GET: Roles/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Rol rol = db.Rol.Find(id);
        if (rol == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(rol);
    }

    // POST: Roles/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Rol rol = db.Rol.Find(id);
        db.Rol.Remove(rol);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

Este es el diagrama ER de mis tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás queriendo guardar en las mismas tablas que te da aspnet identity o quieres guardar en otras tablas?

Comment: Guardar en la aspnet identity, te explico cree una tabla Roles donde agrego roles a la aspnet roles, tengo otra tabla usuarios donde deseo agregar dichos usuarios a la aspnet users, el problema es que no se como asignar el rol a mi tabla usuarios si ya los tengo creados en mi tabla roles.

Comment: Aspnet identity ya viene con soporte para roles. Aquí un caso http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, pero lo que deseo es agregar desde mi controlador usuarios el rol que cree en mi controlador roles y que este se almacene en la tabla asp net users roles de identity, he tratado de hacerlo de esta forma desde el controlador usuarios: usuario.Rol.NameRol, el problema que tengo y disculpen la ignorancia es que en la tabla usuarios tengo un idrol que es la llave foranea de roles, deseo obtener el nombre de rol de ese id y que se guarde en la tabla usuarios y que este a su vez se guarde en el asp net users roles de identity.